# Eclipse external text filter

Tags: eclipse, editor

I'm using PyDev in Eclipse to edit Python.

I'd like to be able to run some lines of Python through an external filter program (one that takes input on stdin and writes to stdout).

I can configure an external tool that can modify the whole file, or I can configure a tool that takes selected lines, but I don't seem to be able to configure a tool that takes selected lines and replaces them in the file with it's output.  Is it possible?

Comment: The question is too abstract. Would you be able to give an example of the external filter program that you have in mind and how you'd like to run it in Eclipse?

Comment: I don't know any way on how to do that out of the box, but my suggestion would be to create your own custom eclipse plugin, AnyEdit (http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) does several selected lines modifications but it's not what you're really looking for. You could try to modify it in order to run your external tool and replace the code.

Comment: I've got AnyEdit, and it's handy, but it doesn't solve my problem.  Unfortunately I'm not a java programmer, and (afaik) you can't write eclipse plugins in Python.

Comment: @xorsyst: regarding not being able to write eclipse plugins in Python you can always bend that a bit and use Jython, having all your code in Python and just a single Java class that would define the eclipse's plugin interface and delegate to your python code. Once again it's not what you're looking for but, it might be something to think as a "last resort measure".

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1480922/91238

This answer gets you halfway there.  I don't know how to get stdout of the external tool into the editor.  You can at least copy/paste from the console pane.

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work very well with multiple lines of selected text.